# Main function's subfunctions should terminate main function

Tags: clean-code, functions

So if I have a big function I break it to smaller ones to increase readability.

If I have parts in my big function where I want it to return. I want my subfunctions to have the ability to make the main function terminate as well, if a condition is true in the subfunction. What's the best approach for this?

Making subfunctions return a bool variable seems messy with the too many ifs in the main function.

**OriginalFunction**

```
void MainFunction()
{

    //DoStuff1
    ....
    ....
    if(condition1)
        return;

    //DoStuff2
    ....
    ....
    if(condition1)
        return;

    //DoStuff3
    ....
    ....
    if(condition1)
        return;

    //DoStuff4
    ....
    ....
    if(condition1)
        return;

}
```

**Modified Function**

```
void MainFunctionModified()
{
    if(DoStuff1())
        return;

    if(DoStuff2())
        return;

    if(DoStuff3())
        return;

    if(DoStuff4())
        return;

}

bool DoStuff1()
{
    ....
    ....
    if(condition1)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: To be honest, your "modified" version is very readable. I would just go with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the language you are using uses lazy evaluation of expressions, then you can just link those sub functions with `&&`'s. It'll then end the expression evaluation, and thus the function calling, on the first `false` that's returned:

```
void MainFunctionModified()
{
    DoStuff1() &&
    DoStuff2() &&
    DoStuff3() &&
    DoStuff4();
}

bool DoStuff1()
{
    ....
    ....
    return condition1;
}

...
```

Comment: Considering the question as asked, it's hard to imagine a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to let the submethods throw exceptions that propogate to the caller.  This isn't a good fit all the time, but if the submethods are only operating by being called from the main method (and not part of a larger network of classes), it could work and is easier to implement (and read, I think) than the ICommand suggestion:

```
public void main() {

    try {
        sub1();
        sub2();     
        // finalize as if all were successful
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // do whatever
    }   
}

private void sub1() {
    //...
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}

private void sub2() {
    //...
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

In both the ICommand suggestion and the chained-and suggestion, these rely on the submethods returning a status (bool) depending on whether the method was successful.  Myself, I tend to avoid returning like that and prefer to assume the method was successful unless there's an exception thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Your function could benefit from implementing the **command pattern**, or at least a simplified version of it.

You'll have to create an "ICommand" interface (I'll be using C# notation since I'm more fluent with it)

```cs
public interface ICommand
{
    bool Execute();
}
```

And then implement each command class with one of the parts you want executed. Then, in your main function, you'll have:

```cs
void MainFunction()
{
    var commands = new List<ICommand>
    {
        //initialize command classes here, or have another method return a command list
    }
    foreach(var command in commands) 
    {
        if (!command.Execute()) return; //you can also break out of the foreach, roll back, or do other actions in case of failure
    }
}
```

You can also take a more slim and functional approach to the above method, although less flexible since you don't have an expandable interface:

```cs
void MainFunction()
{
    var functions = new List<Func<bool>>
    {
        //initialize with a list of function delegates here
    }
    foreach(var function in functions) 
    {
        if (!function()) return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With most languages, a function must always return to the caller. Typically, if you need the program to terminate without the caller continuing after the function call, the function will return a value and the caller will check for it, as you are doing in your example.

Some languages also offer a direct way to terminate the process (for example, .NET programs can use [`Environment.Exit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit(v=vs.110).aspx)), but this is usually not the best way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

From your **OriginalFunction**, If your `DoStuff` operations represent the behaviors your `MainFunction()` is expected to execute in their own `conditions`. With that many branches, you might consider using the **State Pattern**.

The [**State Pattern**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) effectively reduce the complexity of branching strategies and make the code more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score -1):

This is one of the reasons C included the `setjmp/longjmp` functions: Unwind a call stack of considerable depth. This approach does, however have some dangers of its own - if something in the call chain did a considerable resource allocation, that resource might be leaked, so must be handled with care.

Other languages have language components similar to `setjmp/longjmp`.

Another approaches could be a typical state machine structure:

```
while (state  != STATE_EXIT) {
   switch (state):
      case FUNC1:
         state = doFunc1();
         break;
      case FUNC2:
         state = doFunc2();
      ...
}
```